# How can I check if an Android code change is in a particular release?

Tags: android, git, android-source, repository

I'd like to know which release a particular change to android source has gone into if any.

For example, is latest change at http://code.metager.de/source/history/linux/stable/drivers/nfc/pn533.c in Android 4.3?

How can I determine this?

Answer (score 1):

This file seems to come from linux kernel source code.
So, it's not directly related to the Android version but rather to the kernel version (same kernel version can be used with different Android version, and same Android version can run with different kernel versions).

If your Android is an AOSP build, you can find the kernel source code used in one of these repos (depending on your device) :

https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/omap/

https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/samsung/

https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/tegra/

https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/

If it's not, you have to look at kernel source code released by the device manufacturer.